# how to force nhibernate to set the foreign key of the child item?

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, collections, foreign-keys

i have a collection in the mapping:

```
<bag name="Values" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" inverse="true">
  <key column="[TemplateId]"/>
  <one-to-many class="MyNamespace.Value, MyLib"/>
</bag>
```

the Value object has a foreign key [TemplateId]. both entities has their  generator set to "identity".
when i call session.Save() for the parent Template object, the Value objects has their [TemplateId] (the foreign key) set to zero, so an SQL exception appears.
how do i forse nhibernate to set the FK value for the child items to the value of the inserted parent object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've managed it myself:
the only thing i was needed to do is to design child object mapping and persistent the following way:

```
<many-to-one name="Template" class="MyNamespace.Template, MyLib"
                 column="[TemplateId]" not-null="true" />
```

so the child object has a reference to the parent instead of the parent's Id

Comment: the solution was taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917845/nhibernate-parent-mapping-does-not-create-child-foreign-key